# Chrome extension on a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to open your chrome extension on a new tab? I would like to be able to create a chrome browser that has same approach like the bookmark manager. See figure 1.0 below

[image]

I would like my application to like/have an address

```
chrome://personalize_calendar_stuff
```

is that possible? I can't find on the manifest references.

Comment: See [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:new%20tab) and [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) for override pages

Comment: it looks good but it lacks on what I want to achieved. I only want to open a my from another tab when they click the button(my app) or navigate directly typing  "chrome://personalize_calendar_stuff" I download an extension before and it does what I want exactly, it was a note keeper, can't really remember the name of that extension.

Comment: You can't define your own chrome:// URL.

Comment: Oh I see. thanks for the info @wOxxOm. Anyway I downloaded the ntp_zip example from the link you gave. Is there any other way to you know open my app in manner same as that but not on every newtab. Only open newtab if they click the icon of my extension. I'm sure it's possible. I'm scraping through the doc tutorials now.

Comment: Use the standard `target="_blank"` attribute in your html or chrome.tabs.create in js.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @wOxxOm for giving me an idea.

I added this script on my *index.js*

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "main.html"});
})
```

and on below is an example of manifest file I used.

```
{
  "name" : "Testing Chrome",
   "version": "1.0",

   "background":
   {
         "scripts": ["index.js"]
   },
   "description": "A testing example app",
   "permissions":[
      "tabs",
   ],
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",

    "browser_action": {
"default_title": "testing chtome",
"default_icon": "icon.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2
  }
```